# Apache Ignite not updating cache with null value

Tags: java, spring, ignite

Hi I am using apache ignite in my spring application.
When a service request is made with paramter that doesnt exists in database it throws an exception

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "channel")
public Channel getChannelByCode(long ChannelCode) {
    Query<Channel> query = channelDao.createQuery();
    query.filter(Channel.mongoChannelCode, ChannelCode);
    return channelDao.findOne(query);
}
```

when `channelDao.findOne(query);` returns null ignite throws null pointer exception. Below is the stack trace.

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Ouch! Argument cannot be null: val] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Ouch! Argument cannot be null: val
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridArgumentCheck.notNull(GridArgumentCheck.java:48)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridArgumentCheck.notNull(GridArgumentCheck.java:61)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.putAsync0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:481)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.putAsync(GridCacheAdapter.java:2541)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.put(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:460)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2215)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.put(IgniteCacheProxy.java:1214)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCache.put(SpringCache.java:71)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:82)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:626)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:340)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.getChannelByCode(Unknown Source)
    at in.til.tp.commonpage.controller.BadgeController.getUserBadges(BadgeController.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is already fixed and the fix will be included in Ignite 1.8: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3634

Comment: great ... as an alternative i am using @Cacheable(value = "channel", unless = "#result == null")  . can you suggest any other/better alternative

Comment: This will remove the exception, but the `null` value will still not be cached. This means that next time you call this method, you will execute it again. I don't think there is a clean workaround with 1.7 though.

Comment: ok ... i can live with that till 1.8 is released. can you tell me what is the date for 1.8 release